# Oregon Pacific Jointer

Tags: jointer

Local lumber yard in Oregon is selling this jointer. I can not find any information on this jointer nor “Oregon Pacific” as a whole for the life of me. Does anyone have any information on either? Much appreciated! [image]

Comment: Plenty of machinery gets a low volume private label. You’ll have to judge based on the country of origin, the condition of the unit itself, and how the price compares with other similar units. While we don’t really encourage opinion-based answers, if you filled in some of those details, we might have some additional information to offer.

Comment: This looks a lot like my old Craftsman jointer/planer Model 351 227240 ( 4' bed, 2 HP, 120v, 10.8A, 6oHz). I got it, used, 15 years ago, give it moderate use and it has served me fine without problems. The plate on mine says it is a 3 cutter, 15,000 cuts / minute with a fence tilt of 45 degrees inward and a 1/8" max. cut depth. Could be both of these were from the same manufacturer.

Comment: I came across a couple of references to Oregon Pacific trying searches in Google, but nothing with any detail regrettably. With these sorts of purchases you can go into it in a *see how it goes* kind of way. It's a bit of a \*gulp* if you have no prior experience refurbing an old machine, but in general no power tools of a certain vintage were actual junk so you can use as a starting position that it's more than likely decent or better. And there are multiple restorations and rebuilds of old jointers on YouTube to use as a model for the steps you might take bringing this back [contd]

Comment: ...so you won't be working completely in the blind should you choose to take it on. De-rusting the working surfaces is generally a snap, and if you find minor pitting it's usually irrelevant (a cosmetic issue only). The motors can often be fine, only requiring a rudimentary cleaning with *maybe* new bearings (and these are almost always common parts that are still available as spares in case you didn't know). Looks like it might have gotten a new lead not too long ago so you might not need to fit a new one yourself, although that's generally an easy enough job that can be done safely by users.

Comment: There's an "Oregon Pacific" company in Oregon who makes milling machines. I think I'd start there: https://oregonpacificco.com/